# Jmeter - how to get higher randomize effect?

Tags: multithreading, http, web, server, jmeter

I need to simulate "real traffic" on Web farm, by other words I need to generate high peaks but as well periods which less or even no HTTP requests (hits) at all. Reason for that is to test some atomized mechanisms for adding and reducing CPU and memory for Web servers itself (that is another story). That is why I need "totally random" sceneries when I have loads but as well period with zero or less traffic (so I can add or reduce compute power).

This is situation that I get now, as you can see I always have some avg load its always around some number of hits, even if I change 10 to 100 threads. Values (results) will always have some average value. There are no periods with less or more traffic which would be separated be +10 mints or so, only by few seconds.
[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0wqJ.png)

I would like to get "higher" variations by HITS/REQUESTS with some time breaks between it.
Situation that I want: [**i.stack.imgur.com/I4LhU.png**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4LhU.png)

I tried several timers but no success and I do not want to use "Ultimate Thread Group" and similar components because I want test to be totaly randome and not predefined with time breaks and pause periods (thread delays). I would like test which will be totally randomized by it self - which could for example generate from 1 to 100 users per XY time.

This is my current Jmeter setup: **i.stack.imgur.com/I4LhU.png**

I do not know if I am missing some parameter in current setup or there is totally another way to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you really want (I strongly believe that the test needs to be repeatable, not random), I would suggest using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for this. Despite the word "Constant" in its name you can use [a Function or a Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) there, for instance [__Random()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and you will get different controllable "spikes" each iteration.

Moreover, you put a [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and amend its value via [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) while the test is running

Comment: Can you be more specific please? concrete example. Tnx